# How to deactivate uppercase check in cygwin folder autocompletion?

Tags: autocomplete, cygwin, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

When navigating a file hierarchy under Cygwin, pressing tab after `cd + a few characters` will replace those few characters by the name of a directory whose name starts by the same characters, if such a directory is present in the current folder.
However, the test seems to be case-sensitive. How to deactivate the case-sensitivity ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
 set completion-ignore-case On
```

(This is for bash, which I'm pretty sure cygwin uses.)

**EDIT:**
This change will only take effect for the duration of your current shell session.  To make it permanent, you need to add that line to your `~/.inputrc` file.